# Intersection of two dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a simple way to find the intersection of a two dimensional array? For example:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr2 = [5,6,7,8]
arr3 = [5]
bigarr = [arr1,arr1,arr3]
```

I know that it's possible to do:

```
intersection = arr1 & arr2 & arr3 # => 5
intersection = big_arr[0] & big_arr[1] & big_arr[2] # => 5
```

but the number of elements in `big_arr` will vary. I was wondering if there was a simple way to intersect all the elements in `big_arr` regardless of the number of elements.

Comment: The intersection is not `5`, it is `[5]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) like

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr2 = [5,6,7,8]
arr3 = [5]
bigarr = [arr1,arr2,arr3]
bigarr.reduce(:&) # => [5]
```

Comment: I know.. that's why I was walking around the SO.. :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want: a method with a pretty face or one that is first to finish line? My friend @Arup has supplied one; I'll offer the another.

**Code**

```
def heavy_lifter(a)
  wee_one = a.min_by(&:size)
  return [] if wee_one.empty?
  wee_loc = a.index(wee_one)
  counts = wee_one.each_with_object({}) { |e,h| h.update(e=>1) }
  nbr_reqd = 1
  a.each_with_index do |b,i|
    next if i == wee_loc
    b.each do |e|
      cnt = counts[e]
      case
      when cnt.nil?
        next
      when cnt == nbr_reqd
        counts[e] = cnt + 1
      when cnt < nbr_reqd
        counts.delete(e)
        return [] if counts.empty?
      end
    end
    nbr_reqd += 1
  end
  counts.keys.each { |k| counts.delete(k) if counts[k] < nbr_reqd }
  counts.keys
end
```

**Example**

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
a2 = [5,6,7,8]
a3 = [5]
a = [a1,a2,a3]

heavy_lifter(a)
  #=> [5]
```

**Explanation**

Here's how the method works:

- select the smallest array (`wee_one`). To simplify the explanation, assume it is the first element of `a`.
- convert `wee_one` to a counting hash, `counts`, where `counts[e] = 1` for each element of `wee_one`.
- iterate through the remaining arrays.
- keys of `counts` will be removed as arrays are processed.
- after all calculations are complete, `counts.keys` equals the intersection of all arrays.
- after `nbr_reqd` arrays have been processed (including `wee_one`), `counts[k]` equals the number of those arrays that have been found to contain `k`. Obviously, if `counts[k] < nbr_reqd`, key `k` can be removed from `counts` (but we will not remove such keys until our attention is drawn to them, or at the end).
- suppose we are now to process the array `b` at offset `nbr_reqd`, meaning `nbr_reqd` arrays have been processed (including `wee_one` at offset zero).  For each element `e` of `b`, we obtain `cnt = counts[e]`. There are four possibilities:

  - `cnt == nil`, in which case there is nothing to be done;
  - `cnt < nbr_reqd`, in which case key `e` is removed from `counts`;
  - `cnt == nbr_reqd`, meaning `e` has been present in all previous arrays processed, in which case we execute `counts[k] = cnt + 1`; and
  - `cnt == nbr_read+1`, meaning `e` has been present in all previous arrays processed and is a duplicate of another `e` in `b` that has already been processed, in which case nothing is to be done.
- `nbr_reqd` is incremented by one and the process is repeated for the next array.
- after all arrays have been processed, all that remains is to remove each key `k` in `counts` for which `counts[k] < nbr_reqd`.

**Cutie method**

```
def cutie(a)
  a.reduce(:&)
end
```

**Test data**

```
def test(mx, *sizes)
  sizes.map { |sz| Array.new(sz) { rand(mx) } }
end
```

For example:

```
test(10,5,6,7)
  #=> [[9, 1, 5, 1, 1], [0, 8, 7, 8, 5, 0], [5, 1, 7, 6, 7, 9, 5]]
```

**Benchmark code**

```
require 'benchmark'

def bench(tst)
  Benchmark.bm(12) do |bm|
    bm.report 'cutie' do
      cutie(tst)
    end
    bm.report 'heavy_lifter' do
      heavy_lifter(tst)
    end
  end
end
```

**Benchmark results**

```
tst = test(1_000_000, 400_000, 600_000, 800_000) 

cutie(tst).size
  #=> 81929
cutie(tst).sort == heavy_lifter(tst).size
  #=> true

bench(tst)
                   user     system      total        real
cutie          1.610000   0.030000   1.640000 (  1.639736)
heavy_lifter   1.800000   0.020000   1.820000 (  1.824281)
```

```
sizes = (700_000..890_000).step(10_000).to_a
  #=> [700000, 710000, 720000, 730000, 740000,
  #    750000, 760000, 770000, 780000, 790000,
  #    800000, 810000, 820000, 830000, 840000,
  #    850000, 860000, 870000, 880000, 890000]

tst = test(1_000_000, *sizes) 

bench(tst)
                   user     system      total        real
cutie         14.090000   0.440000  14.530000 ( 14.679101)
heavy_lifter   5.830000   0.030000   5.860000 (  5.935438)
```

Comment: To be sadly honest, I was looking for cutie because I could not even begin to fathom how to create heavy_lifter.  Now I might have to spend the rest of the day trying to figure out what heavy_lifter is doing.

Comment: I'd go with `cutie` as well, but I've always been a sucker for a pretty face. I added some explanatory comments.

Comment: You should show your algorithm to Matz!... He might think to change the implementation of `#reduce`.. :)

Comment: @Arup, there has to be quite a number of large arrays to intersect before it makes any sense, and `&` is just for two. Oh, wait. You said `reduce`, not `&`. I must think about that.